# Reledpar paragraphed footnotes width within sized ledgroup

Tags: luatex, footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

### Background of the question

The goal is to typeset Greek fragments and their translations side-by-side. The style guide prescribes that the Greek should be set with a hanging indent of 8mm. The notes (printed directly beneath the fragment) should be flush with the main body of the text.

### Problem:

When using the `ledgroupsized` enviroment of reledmac and the `paragraph` footnotes setting (`\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}`) the notes are flush with the left margin of the sized ledgroup. When on the `normal` arrangement setting, they follow the left margin of the document.

I want the alignment of the normal arrangement with the structure of the paragraph. Is there a way to achieve this?

### Code exemplifying the problem:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[%
  series={A, B, C, D},
  noend,
  noeledsec, 
  ]{reledmac}
\usepackage[parledgroup]{reledpar}

\Xarrangement[A]{normal}

\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}

\Xarrangement[C]{twocol}

\Xarrangement[D]{threecol}

\begin{document}
\numberlinefalse

\begin{pages}

\numberlinetrue
\lineation{pstart}

% Text to be typeset on the left page; editions
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
   
\pstart[%
 \section*{ Title for original text }
]

\begin{ledgroupsized}[r]{107mm}
Ipsa eveniet \edtext{}{\Afootnote{Footnote series A: normal form}}
laborum \edtext{}{\Bfootnote{Footnote series B: paragraph form}}doloremque alias necessitatibus consequatur aut et. Id nostrum in facilis iusto omnis nemo est. Ea voluptas sunt aut alias quo. Repellendus \edtext{}{\Dfootnote{Footnote series D: three columns}}harum sit pariatur velit assumenda dolores. Quisquam consectetur molestiae dolores et est et.

Qui eos sit dolore aliquam eveniet. Velit minu\edtext{}{\Cfootnote{Footnote series C: two columns}} s suscipit aut inventore voluptatibus doloremque dolores. Ea omnis porro consequatur reprehenderit et aliquid ut blanditiis.
\end{ledgroupsized}
\pend
\end{Leftside}

% Text to be typeset on the right page; translations
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart[%
\section*{English translation}
]

\begin{ledgroup}
Stet oportere no vel, nec in affert regione deseruisse. Case natum appareat ad eam. Vim an veniam essent discere, ex iuvaret euripidis mei. Pri elitr ignota audire te, mel et decore expetendis, ne vel prima saperet vulputate. Atqui vidisse conclusionemque pri no, pro ne sumo nihil verterem.

Te vix quem essent vidisse. Mucius apeirian lobortis quo no. Nam diam denique ex. Antiopam iracundia vituperatoribus ne vel, amet ridens expetendis at vel, at quot mazim errem vis. Omnium neglegentur disputationi duo id, usu posse tincidunt ne, eos quaeque explicari liberavisse ei.
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}

\pagebreak
\Pages[mainmatter]
\end{document}
% End of document
```

### Output:

[image: Screenshot of the several allignment options]

Comment: Is the 107mm setting the only reason for using `ledgroupsized`? If so, maybe have a look at the usage of `\leftskip` with just regular `pstart` and `pend` here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329163/leftskip-rightskip-and-centering-in-reledmac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329163/leftskip-rightskip-and-centering-in-reledmac)

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. If the notes are specific to the `ledgroup` I would expect them to be aligned commensurate with the group. If they are notes in general then align with the general text.

Comment: @PeterWilson Maybe I do not understand the proper function of the ledgroup. The notes are specific to the text in the `ledgroup` and the styling requirements (indented text, non-indented notes) are fixed.

It also seems strange to me that the indentation is only applied to the notes if they are in `paragraph` setting.

Comment: @henryflower I want to use the `ledgroup` environment because I have multiple Greek fragments on the left pages with each their own notes. The notes are not part of the original fragments but are a part of the editor/translators work, which is why they do not need the indent. Using `\leftskip` within a `ledgroup` also indents the paragraphed footnotes.